# Extract certificate information of a process from memory dump

Tags: memory, memory-dump, digital-forensics

I have a `.dmp` file for `googleupdate.exe` process. I wanted to check in WinDbg this process has a certificate or not in order to detect this process has modified or not because this process has tried access `lsass.exe` multiple time.

How can I check the integrity and also maliciousness of this process in WinDbg? I have just a memory dump from that process and nothing more. I should check it in WinDbg.

Comment: This paper seems to exactly match your question: [On Challenges in Verifying Trusted Executable Files in Memory Forensics - DFRWS 2020 EU](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2666281720300123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the PE loader does not explicitly load up the certificate details into the new process at run-time.

In the binary, the certificates are referenced via the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY directory; but they are not in a section that is mapped into virtual memory. The data is instead appended to the file.

You might get lucky and find the cert data has been mapped via a memory mapped file, or if you captured a full kernel dump you might have a copy of it. Otherwise you will have to try and source the file from the computer.

Your best bet is to manually compare the code-in-memory to a valid copy of googleupdate.

Also keep in mind that the source binary could be completely valid, but the behavior changed at run-time (via code injection, etc.). So even if you could easily validate the integrity of the certificate, it wouldn't detect rogue threads, hooked functions, etc.